# Broken part of aerator stuck in faucet

Tags: faucet, stuck

My aerator got broken and the disconnected part is stuck in the faucet. Now if I don't unscrew the disconnected part, I can't install a new aerator. Please advise how to remove it. thank you.
[image: faucet]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

External circlip pliers may grip that better to undo, especially compared to normal pliers.

Answer (score 1):

If just yoinking the white plastic bit out (as suggested in other answers) doesn't work, it appears that 3 of 6 flats of a large hex socket are visible in the picture:

[image: edited version of one of the OP's original pics]

A simple Allen key/hex wrench will unscrew that if it happens to be screwed in. That does look to be fairly large, maybe 10-14mm, so you might have to go to the store to find one. While you're test fitting the keys to ensure that you're getting one that fits, a few twists might just loosen it enough that you won't actually need one to get it the rest of the way out.<sup>*</sup>

I've found that larger hex keys often come as sockets that would fit onto a ratchet, as opposed to the "standard" 90° bent Allen key/hex wrench that many are familiar with, so if you can't find one large enough in that section of the tools, take a wander down to the socket section - they may have one there.

There also appears to be a small notch in the right hand flat. You may be able to stick a small flat-blade screwdriver into that notch and get the plastic bit to turn, or use the edge of the blade to push it in a circle. That may be worth a shot before heading off to the store.

---

<sup>*</sup>Some folk may consider such "borrowing" of tools somewhat unethical. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Where I live, many auto parts stores have loaner tool kits that you pay for, take home to do the work on your car, then return to the store for a full refund. You could certainly borrow tools from there, or, if you ask nicely, they'll probably just let you borrow one off the shelf for 3 seconds of work.

Answer (score 0):

insert small screwdriver and push it out it, it is not holding to anything, just stuck.

If that does not work use pointy pliers and grab it to remove.